# Visual Basic, Form1 checkbox Function in Module can't see checkbox

Tags: checkbox, module

Visual Basic 2008:
Form1 design page I have a checkbox with text.
 I also have module1 with a series of Functions , All of which are working.
I have come across an idea to  make one of these functions do a count of items passed to it and processed. (simple every time increments by 1 within a loop)
However I don't always want this count. Hence the Form1 checkbox.
So in the Module - Function I have an if checkbox.checked then do the count
if not then dont do it..

But From the module - function I can't see the checkbox state.

Help please

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Hi Fjodr, many thanks for the response. Things have changed with the code and my knowledge. I have moved the code from the Modules and placed it in Form1 . I now have no problems. It seems it can be done, but is far more complex than it needs to be. so its been a simple move of a function out of the Module into the Form1. Job done all works well.